# No route matches(resources invested)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In routes.rb I have:

```
 resources :dtests do
    resources :dquestions
 end
```

All activities and routes of type "/ dtests/2/dquestions/3" working properly, but when I try to enter "dtests/2/dquestions", an error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"dquestions", :locale=>:en, :dtest_id=>#<Dquestion id: 1, question_text: "dfs", count_answer: 4, dtest_id: "1", created_at: "2013-06-01 09:32:41", updated_at: "2013-06-01 09:32:41">}
```

In server log:

```
Dquestion Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "dquestions".* FROM "dquestions" WHERE "dquestions"."dtest_id" = 1
default_url_options is passed options: {}

  Rendered dquestions/index.html.erb within layouts/application (39.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 106ms

ActionController::RoutingError
```

Tell me, please, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here:

```
:dtest_id=>#<Dquestion id: 1, question_text: "dfs", count_answer: 4, dtest_id: "1", created_at: "2013-06-01 09:32:41", updated_at: "2013-06-01 09:32:41">
```

Somehow you pass the whole object instead of the id. Can't tell why `to_param` is not automatically triggered.

Anyway just prepend `.id` to your object in the url helper.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was resolved changing url helpers on index page